# Combine first two columns of a single csv file into another column

Tags: linux, shell, csv, awk, sed

So I have a large CSV file (in Gb) where I have multiple columns, the first two columns are :

```
 Invoice number|Line Item Number
```

I want a unix / linux /ubuntu command which can merge this two columns and create a new column which is separated by separator ':', so for eg : If invoice number is 64789544 and Line Item Number is 234533, then my Merged value should be

```
 64789544:234533
```

Can it really be achieved, If yes can the merged column is possible to be added back to the source csv file.

Comment: I have answer to your additional query in the comment! Let me know if it works as expected for you :) If it helped you you can vote up/accept my answer

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `sed` command:

```
$ cat large.csv 
Invoice number|Line Item Number|Other1|Other2
64789544|234533|abc|134
64744123|232523|cde|awc

$ sed -i.bak 's/^\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)/\1:\2/' large.csv

$ cat large.csv                                                                                       
Invoice number:Line Item Number|Other1|Other2
64789544:234533|abc|134
64744123:232523|cde|awc
```

Just be aware that it will take a backup of your input file just in case so you need to have enough space in your file system.

**Explanations:**

- `s/^\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)/\1:\2/` this command will replace the first two field of your CSV separated by `|` and will replace the separator by `:` using back references what will merge the 2 columns.

If you are sure about what you are doing, you can change `-i.bak` in `-i` to avoid taking a backup of the CSV file.

Comment: Alan..Thanks your answer is leading me to some better place. Few things, instead of '|' I have ',' so I replaced your command where you had '|' with ','. I hope I am right. Secondly is there any way to preserve the columns as is and the merged value be seen as a new column.

Comment: @chandresh_cool: for the comma as separator use `s/^\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/\1:\2/` then it is also possible to achieve your second goal by using: `s/^\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)/\1:\2|\1|\2/` (here I am using `|` as separator). I would also recommend that you test it on some small files before going with the big one

Comment: Thanks Alla. For second task I tried this ; sed -i.bak s/^\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/\1:\2,\1,\2/ test.csv , but it did not work.

Comment: @chandresh_cool: You can also go for a `awk` solution `awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{print $1":"$2"|"$0}' ` input_file > output_file but there is no inline mode with awk

Comment: And yes replace FS="|" with FS="," obviously :)

Comment: Thanks Allan...This works. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with this simple sed

```
sed 's/|/:/' infile
```